# Apex 4.2 Region Display Selector - как запомнить предыдущий Selected region

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

В приложении (версия Apex 4.2) на странице реализовал 2 вкладки (к прим. А и Б) через Region Display Selector. На каждой вкладке отдельный Report и отдельная кнопка, которая запускает пересчет.

В свойствах загрузки страницы (Execute on Page Load) указал необходимые строчки дабы скрыть вкладку ShowAll:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Суть проблемы:** При запуске расчета на вкладке Б, у меня после пересчета и повторной загрузки страницы отображается вкладка А.

**Вопрос:** Какое есть решение, чтобы после Submit страницы остаться на владке Б?
Заранее благодарен за комментарии!

Answer (score 1):

У меня APEX 5.1, версии 4.2 под рукой нет. В 5.1 в атрибутах региона с типом `Region Display Selector` есть галочка `Remember Last Selection`. Посмотрите на закладке `Attributes`, скорее всего в 4.2 она тоже была.

**UPD**
Если нет галочки, могу предложить следующую схему:

1. Добавить скрытый итем на страницу.
2. По нажатию на вкладку сохранять название/номер вкладки в итем
3. При загрузке страницы проверять итем в динамик экшене и активировать вкладку
4. В 5-м апексе у итемов есть защита - если он скрыт, а ему установили джаваскриптом другое значение, апекс выдает ошибку. Если в апексе 4.2 есть такая же защита, то итем можно скрыть не через свойство `Item type - Hidden`, а добавлением HTML-аттрибута `style="display: none;"`

Протестировать, сами понимаете, не могу.

Comment: Dmitry, увы, в 4.2 в атрибутах региона такой галочки нет. Слышал, что в версии 5.1. уже встроена подобная опция, но, к сожалению, обновиться возможности нет.

Comment: @OleksiiLytvynenko Добавил новый способ